# How to download public photostream album from icloud.com?

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

My friend shared an album on icloud.com/photostream, by making it public and provided me its url. Now I can download individual photos in the album, but there are over 200 pics. Is there an option to download the whole album at once? I am using chrome on Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in iCloud, but you can install this here in chrome and use it: [Chrome Webstore Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-downloader/cnpniohnfphhjihaiiggeabnkjhpaldj), I have used it for iCloud before and it just works perfect.

Comment: Not working. On the album view page, where several image thumbnails are shown, it does not detect any downloadable image. On clicking a particular image page, it only shows the option to download the current image.